# Holocircularprogressbar Speed

Tags: java, android

I'm having a hard time understanding how the HoloCircularProgressBar's (https://github.com/passsy/android-HoloCircularProgressBar) animation works. When I try changing animate(mHoloCircularProgressBar, null, 1f, 1000) to animate(mHoloCircularProgressBar, null, 1f, 10000) the duration does not multiply by ten. Instead the animation becomes choppy and is only smooth with values less than 1000. How can I slow down the HoloCircularProgress bar so it progresses with an given value of milliseconds?

Answer (score -1):

Below example should help you.

```
private void batteryLevel() {

    BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            context.unregisterReceiver(this);
            int rawlevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
            float level = -1;
            if (rawlevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
                level = (rawlevel * 100) / scale;
            }
            //batterLevel.setText("Battery Level Remaining: " + level + "%");
            animate(pgbTablet, null,level, 10000);
            animate(pgbCase, null, level, 10000);
            tvTblCharging.setText(""+(int)Math.ceil(level));
            tvCaseCharging.setText(""+(int)Math.ceil(level));
        }
    };
    IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    getContext().registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
}
```